# Open a url from a gdk card or invoke the browser

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I'm trying to select a url from a card to be opened by the glass browser. Is there a way to set or invoke this?

The Card API for 'getting a uri' from my examination is for rendering images. 
https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/app/Card#getImage(int)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can open a URL in the built-in browser by starting an activity with an `ACTION_VIEW` intent. For example:

```
String url = "http://www.whatever.com";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
```